# Cannot alter a timestamp column to have a default value as current_timestamp

Tags: mysql, syntax, alter-table

Basically I want to add a new updatedTime column so that it auto set to current_timestamp on updating and creating. Also I want to set the updatedTime column to null for existing rows.
So I try something like below:

1. Add new column and make it default to null
2. Set the new column default to current_timestamp afterward

```
alter table A
    add column updatedTime timestamp null 
        default null on update current_timestamp;

alter table A
    alter column updatedTime set default current_timestamp;
```

The reason is because my table is huge around 7 million rows and it's on live database as well so I try to optimise my query. By doing it this way, I just need to loop through the whole table once for the first query. The second query will only change the table config file.
So I am able to run the first query but the second one got syntax error.

EDIT:
My database is mysql server 5.7

Comment: What is the error message? Is it required to first drop the existing default before setting a new default? Btw, [MySQL 5.7 alter table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) for reference.

Comment: The syntax is `ALTER [COLUMN] col_name {SET DEFAULT literal | DROP DEFAULT}`. `current_timestamp` is NOT literal - it is a function. So you receive the error  message.

Comment: hmm so what should the literal be in my case? or there are no ways.